# XUL Textbox inside Popup not working

Tags: textbox, popup, xul

I am working on creating a Firefox extension. I have added a textbox inside a popup. The popup opens on clicking on a toolbar button. The textbox is appearing but does not let me edit it. I have not given any read only attributes.
Here is the code:

```
    <popupset id="myPopupSet">
    <popup id="trial-popup" noautohide="true" position="after_start">
    <vbox>
    <label value="Enter your name:"/>
   <textbox id="identfier_box" value="This is some text."/>
   </vbox>
   </popup>
   </popupset>

<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
<toolbarbutton id="mybutton"
    class="toolbarbutton-1"
    label="Identifier"
    popup="trial-popup"
insertbefore="urlbar-container" />
```

can anyone let me know why there is this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want is a panel and not a popup.

Change `<popup>` to `<panel>` and you have what you want.